# Rewrite local previous commit history without creating new commits

Tags: git

I have a local git repository with 6 commits which are not pushed remotely

```
af8b643 (tag: v2.0) HEAD@{11}: commit: standard version can work
96a57f9 HEAD@{12}: commit: multiple tries succeed
8b781e5 HEAD@{13}: reset: moving to 8b781e5
51a5f96 HEAD@{14}: commit: stupid version can work
abcdc39 HEAD@{15}: reset: moving to abcdc39
8b781e5 HEAD@{16}: commit: Emply zip to handle multiple try-except
abcdc39 HEAD@{17}: commit (initial): Parse the web front jobs
```

I'd like to rewrite `51a5f96 HEAD@{14}: commit: stupid version can work` to `Original Version to Keep the Naive Tech`,

I tried to follow the https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History and multiple answers here using `git rebase -i HEAD~2`,

Now the commit history is entirely messed.

```
5d97cfa (HEAD) HEAD@{0}: commit (amend): Original Version to Keep the Naive Tech
abcdc39 HEAD@{1}: rebase -i (start): checkout HEAD~2
c340589 HEAD@{2}: rebase -i (pick): add tag v2.0
1d23365 HEAD@{3}: rebase -i (reword): Keep the original versiont to keep the naive techs
51a5f96 HEAD@{4}: rebase -i: fast-forward
abcdc39 HEAD@{5}: rebase -i (start): checkout HEAD~2
e392cd4 HEAD@{6}: commit: add tag v2.0
51a5f96 HEAD@{7}: rebase -i (start): checkout 51a5f96
141c0f2 (master) HEAD@{8}: rebase -i (finish): returning to refs/heads/master
141c0f2 (master) HEAD@{9}: rebase -i (start): checkout master
141c0f2 (master) HEAD@{10}: commit (amend): Encapulate multiple tries with function.:
af8b643 (tag: v2.0) HEAD@{11}: commit: standard version can work
96a57f9 HEAD@{12}: commit: multiple tries succeed
8b781e5 HEAD@{13}: reset: moving to 8b781e5
51a5f96 HEAD@{14}: commit: stupid version can work
abcdc39 HEAD@{15}: reset: moving to abcdc39
8b781e5 HEAD@{16}: commit: Emply zip to handle multiple try-except
abcdc39 HEAD@{17}: commit (initial): Parse the web front jobs
```

Eight more commits were generated.

I am simply intending to change one previous commit, could it be achieved in a straight way?

Comment: Please include _all_ the steps you took _after_ you ran `git rebase -i HEAD~2`.  I suspect that you took a wrong turn somewhere, and before giving you an answer we need to right this problem.

Comment: What options (`pick`, `reword`, ...) did you select when presented with the list of commits?

Comment: Are you using `git reflog` for those listings? What does `git log -10 --oneline` show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to how git store data (as a [Directed Acyclic Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) where a commit point to its parent(s) by its hash ), that's simply not possible to update a commit without updating all the children commits.

> Now the commit history is entirely messed.

And what you show use is the `reflog`, not the commit history. And it is its goal to keep track of all the commits created  (i.e. all the commits pointed successively by `HEAD`) so all the ones you created during the rebase are displayed here...

`reflog` is intended to retrieve "lost" commits when you messed.

Use `git log` to display history.

PS: But perhaps you have a duplicate history because the old history (before doing the rebase) is handled by the tag ref `v2.0`. You should decide if you should delete the tag and recreate it on the new history.